# "Raw" Xamarin and MvvmCross

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm still so new to Android that I'm not sure this is even a question, but here goes.
I'm using MvvmCross 5.6.3.
I need to use Xamarin routines like Signature Pad which do not have MvvmCross 'wrappers'.
What do I need to be aware of when introducing Xamarin NuGet packages into my "MvvmCross" project?
Is there a "standard" set of functions/code/techniques that must be used to access 'Xamarin' from 'within' 'MvvmCross' code?
Thank you,
Marc

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an MvvmCross wrapper to use raw Xamarin controls/routines. You can use them as if you weren't using MvvmCross.

The wrappers are made to facilitate the use of the control and to add some bindings so that you can bind some of their properties to the ViewModel easier. But you can do it yourself or don't create the bindings at all and get/set the properties as in raw Xamarin.

> Is there a "standard" set of functions/code/techniques that must be
>   used to access 'Xamarin' from 'within' 'MvvmCross' code?

MvvmCross is created using Xamarin so you don't need anything special to access Xamarin code because it is using Xamarin code.

I'd recommend you to check some of the code of the [MvvmCross' repository](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross) so you can see that is just Xamarin code what it uses and you can explore some of the custom controls to see how they are done, e.g. [MvxLinearLayout](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/bd3a438f8acff76657a743da0669d97254b7aaa6/MvvmCross/Platform/Android/Binding/Views/MvxLinearLayout.cs).

I've already used `Signature Pad` as in "raw Xamarin" so ask if you have any doubts about it.

HIH